# How to transpose a matrix without using t() function in r

Tags: r, function, matrix, transpose

I know theres a function on R that allows you to transpose any matrix but was wondering how I would go about transposing a matrix without using this (ie. making own function)

How would I write this as my own function?

```
transpose <- function(M)

M <- matrix(data, nrow= (), ncol= (), byrow = TRUE) 
output <- matrix(data, nrow=ncol, ncol=nrow, brow = FALSE)
```

Please note I've only just started using r so please don't be harsh.

Comment: Do you know how to make functions in general? Learn to make a basic function first, then think about how you transpose a matrix using pencil and paper, then try to write it in R, then if you get stuck, come back here and post your attempt.

Comment: My general recommendation for my students is to first think of the algorithm and how you would implement it. Start coding. When you get stuck, search the internet and when you've exhausted all options (possibly after days of searching), post a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: One way to do it would be `transpose <- function(x) matrix(x, ncol(x), nrow(x), byrow=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transposing a matrix is just swapping its columns to rows.
This can be done with the following code:

```
transpose <- function(M) sapply(1:nrow(M), function(i) M[i,])
```

Answer (score -1):

May be the worst idea but at least giving the trasposed matrix would be:

- Build another matrix `M2`
- Assing to `M2[i,j]`the value of `M[j,i]`

Code:

```
    M2 <- M
    for (i in 1:nrow(M2)){
       for (j in 1:ncol(M2)){
             M2[i,j] <- M[j,i]
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It just restates it. Need to see code.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question? I think a function following these steps results on a traspose matrix from the input.

Comment: It might. But the entire point of SO is to answer a question WITH CODE.

Comment: @42- Ok, I have modified the answer.